# Do realizable systems always have some non-well-founded sets?

Tags: lo.logic, computability, set-theory, domain-theory

Suppose we are standing outside a [realizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realizability) system which admits CZF or a similar [constructive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_set_theory). Then consider the following:

- [LEM](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/excluded+middle) is not realized (e.g. [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4314463/425071))
- The traditional foundation axiom (all sets have a least element when ordered by elementhood) implies LEM (e.g. [`regexmid` in Metamath ILE](https://us.metamath.org/ileuni/regexmid.html))

So, working backwards from outside the system, is it the case that **this system always has some non-well-founded sets?** The internal logic might not be able to see them, of course.

Comment: This is purely an idle curiosity that arose while reading about domain theory. Feel free to send this to MSE or MO if it's off-topic on CS Theory.

Comment: The interest in constructive or non-well-founded set theory has mostly been driven by CS in recent decades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong definition of well-foundedness.

Let $R \subseteq A \times A$ be a relation. Consider the following definitions:

1. $R$ is **inductive** when for all $B \subseteq A$, if $\forall x \in A . (\forall y \in A . y R x \Rightarrow y \in B) \Rightarrow x \in B$ then $B = A$.
2. $R$ has the **minimal subset property** when every inhabited set $B \subseteq A$ has an element $x \in B$ such that, for all $y \in A$, if $y R x$ then $y \not\in B$.
3. $R$ has **no infinite decreasing chains** when there is no $a : \mathbb{N} \to A$ such that $a_{n+1} R a_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

These conditions are classically equivalent, but not intuitionistically. The one that makes sense intuitionistically is the "$R$ is inductive".

CZF and most material set theories either assume as an axiom, or prove from other axioms, that $\in$ is inductive.

As far as realizability models of constructive set theories go, you can choose whether you want them to satisfy the $\in$-induction axiom. (People usually do.)

Answer (score 2):

CZF includes the $\in$-induction axiom, which is the constructively sensible version of the foundation axiom. So everything in one of its models is well-founded in that sense.

However, while I'm no expert, I think this might not be a particularly definitive property. For instance, starting with a (pre)topos, you get a model of CZF/IZF/etc. by considering well-founded trees built using the (pre)topos. But you can also take non-well-founded trees to get models of non-well-founded set theories. I'm not sure there is anything more going on in realizability models of CZF than this—the model construction explicitly picking out objects so that $\in$ is well-founded.